# How to identify a file type without extension in Windows?

Tags: windows, backup, filesystems, forensics

I have a large file of 92.5GB with no file extension inside the `C://` partition called “Free Space” and another sibling one of 260KB I wonder if I can identify this file extension or maybe its origin is it an old backup.

Is there anyway to identify the file contents or so? I tried a tool called TRID but did not work for me. Also the “file” command in Linux showed it’s a data file with no more info.

Comment: Take a look with a binary file viewer, aka hex editor? Might not recognize anything, but it'll stand out if it's text or HTML, etc. I'm guessing it's from some program that wanted to fill in all the free space for some reason

Comment: Given its name it could just be a filler/placeholder, meant to be erased later  to recover 93GB if disk space.  If so it is likely filled with zeros (or a constant pattern). A good way to check it to zip it, it it compresses to something tiny (under 5% of original size) this is very likely the case.

Answer (score 2):

I've used [TRID](http://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html) and the file command, which can identify a [file type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_type) if there is a [magic number in the file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Magic_numbers_in_files), before in such cases, but if they can't identify the file format, another option is to look for [strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_%28computer_science%29) in a file that may allow you to identify the type of file or application that created it. E.g., you might find a text string in the file that identifies the company that produced the software that created the file or even text that identifies the application that created the file. On a Linux or OS X system, you can use the strings command for that purpose - type `man strings` at a shell prompt to see the [strings man page](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/unix/linux/centos/7/man/strings.php) or type `strings -h` on a Linux system to get usage information. You can use the Sysinternals [strings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/strings) program on a Microsoft Windows system for that functionality.

Alternatively, you could examine the file with a [hexadecimal editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal_editor) to look for any [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) text that might aid in identifying the file type. On a Microsoft Windows system, you could use the [Freeware Hex Editor XVI32](http://www.chmaas.handshake.de/delphi/freeware/xvi32/xvi32.htm) for the smaller file; [the author states it can handle files up to 2 GB](http://www.chmaas.handshake.de/delphi/freeware/xvi32/xvi32.htm#features). For the larger file, you could use the commercial program [UltraEdit](http://www.chmaas.handshake.de/delphi/freeware/xvi32/xvi32.htm#features); the developer states "Regarding large files, UltraEdit handles files in excess of 4GB. UltraEdit is disk based. This means it only loads small portions of the file at once into memory so it does not use all the memory and stop other applications from running. However, it does make a temporary copy of the file to achieve this and this can take time for large files." I haven't used that product myself, but it is free for a 30-day trial period.

Comment: Just for reference for when you do look at the HEX, here is an accumulated list of known file signatures:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures

Answer (score -1):

You are most likely out of luck.

You could try the "identify" command to see if it's a recognised image, but that's clutching at straws.

Another alternative to the he editor( or running "strings" across the file to recognised text snippets" may be to run photorec over it and then look at any resulting recovery files it generates to get a feel for the embedded components / files it comprises.

Comment: This post popped up in review as shown here: https://i.imgur.com/P7qAXWh.png at https://superuser.com/review/low-quality-posts/686673 for the reason of "***low-quality because of its length and content***". What are your thoughts on this for any simple correction, comments, etc.?

Answer (score -1):

You could also guess the program and try opening it with that program. I believe most programs will successfully open files they can read even without an extension. It has worked for me on occasion.

Can you not limit the list of possible programs to those installed on the system the file is installed on.

Frankly, the 93gb file size is a bit of a clue. Most software cannot generate files that large.

Database, video, backup and disk image are some of the few that seem credible. Raster image, text file, and 3d model seem impossible or nearly so.

The name is a bit vexing. Why create a file named "free space" and then fill free space with it as one commentator seemed to suggest was going on. If I was doing that for some reason, perhaps to test how a system behaved as it ran out of disk space, I would fill it full of nothing or just a string of the same character. indeed, there are applications that do just that. Is the file filled with "nothing" or a repeating string?

Why do you charactrize the second tiny file as a sibling?

Answer (score -2):

You have the "show extensions of known files types" set to ON in windows explorer file options? The default is OFF, creating the impression many files lack extensions.

Comment: No, it is quite clear it lacks a file filetype extension it does not have one, else he wouldn't have resorted to the TRID tool. "it's a data file with no more info" - A data file is just that a file with not extension.